# Modules 'base' and 'instantapp' contain entry 'assets/crashlytics-build.properties' with different content

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle, dynamic-feature-module

I am generating Signed Build Bundle. 
Instant App Module is launching perfectly in device but when I am generating Signed Build Bundle I got this error.

```
'Modules 'base' and 'instantapp' contain entry 'assets/crashlytics-build.properties' with different content'
```

In my assets folder 'crashlytics-build.properties' file is not showing.

Error logs :

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':quickRide:packageQrReleaseBundle'.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.ValidationException: Modules 'base' and 'AdharVerificationDynamicFeature' contain entry 'assets/crashlytics-build.properties' with different content.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this error, I facing same

Answer (score 1):

i solve this problem by changing the name of file in my module and its worked